# Full Screen Flash Background

Tags: css, flash

Am trying to get a full screen flash movie playing behind my HTML content.

I have succeeded with it doing that, but the problem is it does not stretch full screen.

My DIV:

```
<div id="flashmovie" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute; z-index:-999;left:0;top:0">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="movie" value="resources/video/bg_grass.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="scale" value="exactfit">
        <param name="salign" value="t">
        <embed src="resources/video/bg_grass.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the div? And improve your accept rare before asking more questions!

Answer (score 0):

make its position fixed, with a 100% height and width.
Should probably do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately not - it still shows white margins left/right.

I have the DIV above, just after my body tag, and before the main wrapper of the site (margin:0 auto etc)